# Character encoding issue in SQL Server 2012

Tags: json, sql-server, character-encoding

I have a web application with:

1. A SQL Server database where stored procedures are developed to receive requests and send responses (all in JSON format)
2. A servlet (Tomcat) that handles the exchange
3. A web client application.

The servlet logs each and every request received from the client as well as the response received from the server and sent towards the client.

There are some responses (from the DB) that include special characters (e.g. Greek letters, Centigrade degrees symbol, etc.) that are extracted from some tables.

When inspecting the contents of the tables (from which these symbols are retrieved), they all show as expected.

When inspecting the responses (containing the above mentioned special characters) at the servlet's log, everywhere there was a special character and control character is shown as part of the JSON and, obviously, they disqualify it.

I assume that the issue is somewhere between the "TABLE" and the response message submission, but cant figure out where.

The current collation of the DB is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1255_CI_AS. I found some documentation mentioning the introduction of `_SC` collation options, but I don't see them in the list (DB properties).

Where can I look for the problem and (even better), propose a solution?

### Edit [following Tom's comment]

There is no need for any code for it would add unneeded information.

The situation is:

1. A stored procedure generates a JSON which, when being printed within the Management Studio, correctly shows special characters (e.g. Greek).
2. At the servlet (written in JAVA), the received response from the Stored Procedure is logged into a file where the special character are shown as CONTROL CHARACTERS,
3. All involved SQL variables are declare of type `NVARCHAR(<size>)`.
4. By ***DISQUALIFY*** I meant that the JSON become illegal (therefore the JavaScript flags an error).

So, the question would be:

1. Is there a way in SQL Server to convert those special characters to some representation that would be cleanly transferred from the DB all the way to the JavaScript and will be correctly accepted as a legal JSON? or
2. Are there any configurations (DB, connection, Tomcat, JavaScript's POST header) that would solve the problem?

Comment: Please [edit] to state the actual problem, show some code involved and explain "disqualify it." (JSON is capable of every Unicode [and therefore CP1255] codepoint in string values and keys. )

Comment: @TomBlodget, thank you for your response. Please refer to the **EDIT**.

Comment: As I said, JSON can represent any Unicode strings as values or keys. The problem must be the stored procedure. [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/11a32f/1)

Comment: @TomBlodget, if I replace "micro-litters" (which uses a MU Greek character) with "milli-litters" (i.e. "ml"), the JSON comes out perfect and the client has no issues to digest it. As I wrote/ask, I don't know how to make the MU to be converted to the right encoding. That's my issue, not the procedure.

Comment: Hi FDavidov. I'm a volunteer editor here, and I try to help keep posts tidy for the benefit for future readers. There are a few Meta posts that you may find useful for reference. In particular, we prefer that titles do not have "tag" suffixes or prefixes, since there is a tagging system for that: [see here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253076/472495). Also, we encourage a technical style of writing, so politenesses, appreciations and other conversational items are not necessary: [see here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260778/472495).

Comment: @halfer, **my apologies** but I would not renounce to any positive aspect of the education are received from my parents. _Politeness, appreciations and other conversational items_ are becoming rare these days, and I believe they should be welcome no matter the context they are exercised. Cheers!!!

Comment: I understand that view, but respecting the community is important here, as is understanding the consensus on these matters. Of course, you may lobby for a change of direction if you wish, and that could indeed happen in the future, in the context of the new Code of Conduct and associated cultural shift program.

Comment: @halfer, I'm gladly accepting thetry to  challene(influencing the code of conductmy view on the two matters you raised (politeness and title's tagging) is 180 degrees to what you promoted, and this for a very long list of reasons. Therefore, I would highly appreciate if you could send me a link(or other indications)  through which I could access the Code of Conduct forum. Thanks.

Comment: You will have your work cut out, given that they are fairly established guidelines. The [discussion site is here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/). Raise your themes separately, they might be closed as Too Broad otherwise. I recommend searching on each theme first, to understand current policy, and to show you're arguing from a position of knowledge (my canonical links are probably just the tip of the iceberg). Good luck, have fun, and ping me discussion link(s) if you wish.

Comment: (The [code of conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct) is a different theme, but basically it is a new policy to try to get people to be more patient with each other. I do not think this reduces the need and desire for succinct technical writing, but folks particularly attached to a chatty style may wish to argue in that direction.)

Comment: @halfer, thanks for teh links. Will give it a try as soon as I get some time. In any case, I believe both you and me want the same (though there are some difference in the path). We should try again using  the same GPS navigator :-).